# Run ng build --prod with different environment settings

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, production-environment, package.json

I have different env settings for each customer with each having it's own 
{{custName}}/environment.prod.ts file .
I want to use their respective prod environment files with ng build --prod command.
The problem I'm facing is even after specifiying the environment it's using the default environment.prod.ts

My ***package.json*** has script like

```
{.....
   customer_a : "ng build --prod --environment=custA_prod",
....}
```

In ***angular-cli.json*** I have mentioned the path which goes something like this

```
  "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts",
        "custA_prod": "environments/custA/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Is it possible to use all the features of prod build but with some different environment settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mark as production mode on you enviorement file:

environments/custA/environment.prod.ts File:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  envName: "custA_prod",
  .....
};
```

Or add main.ts your custom check:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production || environment.envName == 'custA_prod') {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 7):

After Angular 6+, angular.cli.json has been replaced by angular.json. We should use --configuration as bellow

**package.json**

```
"build_dev": "npm run && ng build --configuration=test",
```

**angular.json**

```
...
 "configurations": {
.....
"test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with defining relative path of the new environment.

**step 1:**
create a prod environment file for custA inside environment directory.
e.g. *environment.custA.prod.ts*

```
export const environment = { 
   mock: false,
   production: true,
   development: false,
   title: 'prod'
}
```

**step 2:** 
Define environment in *.angular-cli.json*

```
environments: {
  "dev": "environments/environment.app.ts",
   "prod": "environments/environment.app.prod.ts",
   "mock": "environments/environment.app.mock.ts",
   "prod-custA": "environments/environment.custA.prod.ts"
}
```

**step 3:**
Define a script in *package.json*

```
start-prod-custA : "ng build --prod --environment=prod-custA"
```

Comment: No , It was not related to the path